# Installed crypted ubuntu on full hd and forget password of crypt and root

Tags: sudo, password, encryption, root, password-recovery

I installed encrypted ubuntu (fullhd) and forget the root pass and encryptation pass, can anyone explain to me if is posible to recovery the files in this HD, I really need that

Comment: 'Recovering' files without the proper key would be a monumental security hole, negating the entire single purpose of encryption.

Answer (score 7):

**With great security comes great responsibility.  :-)**

So, if you encrypted a partition and forgot the password, and set up no other way to decrypt the partition, *there is no way to recover the files without having the password.* It's an unfortunate consequence of encryption.

Maybe try variations on passwords you've used before or ones you think you remember? Did you write down your passwords anywhere? It's always good to keep backups, so if you have a recent one you can restore from that.

You could try to brute-force the password if it was only a few characters, but this approach is very unlikely to help if the password was reasonably secure.